# What are the possible exceptions in connectionLost when using webclient.Agent?

Tags: python, http, twisted, webclient

I've written an http downloader using webclient.Agent.

The connectionLost function of a body consumer object is called with a reason parameter.

```
def connectionLost(self, reason):
    if isinstance(reason.value, ResponseDone):
        self.df.callback(None)
    else:
        self.df.errback(reason.value)
```

I would really want to know what are the possible exception classes in 'reason'
because I need to catch them all and deal with them later in the calling
function which uses inlineCallbacks.
So far I identified:

`ConnectError, BindError, ConnectionClosed, ResponseFailed`

Is this documented somewhere?
Most of the documentation contains just vague
"...errback with a description of the error..." statements.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to catch them all specifically.  Exception handling respects inheritance: if you try to catch a base class and a subclass is raised, you'll catch that too.  `Exception` is the base class for just about all exceptions in Python, so if you catch that, you'll catch just about everything.

```
try:
    yield agent.request(...)
except Exception as e:
    print 'Oh no, some failure'
else:
    print 'Success'
```

There is no complete list of all the exceptions that `Agent.request` may fail with, because it is impossible to know this list in advance.  Failures may be due to connection setup - but is it a plain TCP connection or an SSL connection for an HTTPS URL?  Perhaps it's a connection over a SOCKS proxy due to an unfortunate user's network configuration.  These may all fail in different ways.  The same applies to the actual HTTP request itself - who knows how the server will behave?  Perhaps it will respond with an unexpected error code, or perhaps it will respond with something Agent isn't even capable of parsing and trigger an exception from the low-level HTTP client protocol implementation.  The parser is hand crafted, so there's probably a lot of different exceptions that could come from that kind of problem.  And then there's the variation on content and transfer encoding, which may invoke lots of different functionality (eg, a gzip decoder) which adds still more possible exceptions.

So, instead of trying to come up with the full list of all of these exceptions at every place you use `Agent.request`, only specifically handle the exception types you know about and have special code for and then handle everything else with an `except Exception`.